# HTTP POST method

Tags: c#

I am developing Window application using c#. I want to upload  using HTTP POST request with MIME type multipart/form-data without user id and password. I tried but it doesn't upload the file & also doesn't give me 403 error. Kindly help me.

Comment: I dont see the POST method set anywhere, and you also need to set the correct header when uploading files, which I believe is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Hi Vinoth, please provide us with code of what you already tried. We will be able to better assist you if we can see your code